# Figuring out autoresizing masks in TwUI - bottom margin?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macos, twui

I'm having some trouble with autoresizing masks.  Here's the deal: I'm using the recently released [`TwUI`](https://github.com/twitter/twui), which takes a lot from UIKit, but it's on the Mac.  That's why I tagged for both iOS & Mac.  So, I create a view that needs to have 40px of margin on the bottom, no matter how large the window is resized vertically.  I'm not allowing horizontal expansion of the window, for multiple reasons.  Here's what a sample looks like of what I'm talking about.  Sorry for the ugly appearance, I'm just using sample views to test.

[image]

Right ho, so see the 40px of black space on the bottom?

I'm creating the red view by doing something like this:

```
CGRect b = self.view.bounds;
b.origin.y += TAB_HEIGHT; //40px
b.size.height -= TAB_HEIGHT;
```

Then I'm creating the view with that frame.

However, as soon as I try to add autoresizing masks on the red view it loses bottom 40px, and just fills the whole view.  For those unfamiliar with `TwUI`, a sample autoresizing mask looks like this:

```
view.autoresizingMask = TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

So, the autoresizing masks take after their iOS counterparts. However, setting that mask does this:

[image]

So my question is, how can I keep a margin on the bottom of this view?

Comment: This could very well be a bug (certainly looks like it to me). TwUI is brand new, so it's probably worth reporting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rob, I have got no trouble autoresizing it.

The following code was what I modified an empty project with TwUI github trunk.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    TUINSView *content = [[TUINSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect b = [window frame];
    b.origin = CGPointZero;
    content.frame = b;

    [window setContentView:content];
    TUIView *viewA = [[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    viewA.frame = content.bounds;
    viewA.backgroundColor = [TUIColor blackColor];
    [content setRootView:viewA];
    viewA.autoresizingMask = TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize;
    TUIView *viewB = [[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    viewB.backgroundColor = [TUIColor redColor];
    b = viewA.bounds;
    b.origin.y+=30;
    b.size.height-=30;
    viewB.frame = b;
    [viewA addSubview:viewB];
    viewB.autoresizingMask = TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize;
}
```

EDIT:
I coded my TUIViewController's loadView like this, it works so far so well.

```
- loadView {
    TUIView *v = [[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    tableView = [[TUITableView alloc] initWithFrame:v.bounds style:TUITableViewStylePlain];
    [tableView scrollToTopAnimated:NO];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize;
    document = [[BBSDocDocument alloc] init];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    CGRect rect = [v bounds];
    [v addSubview:tableView];
    [self setView:v];
}
```

EDIT 2:
My code with TUIViewController subclass:

```
//TestVC.h:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TUIKit.h"

@interface TestVC : TUIViewController {
@private
    TUIView *viewA;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
@end


//TestVC.m
@implementation TestVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize;
}


//application delegate:
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    TUINSView *content = [[TUINSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect b = [window frame];
    b.origin = CGPointZero;
    content.frame = b;

    [window setContentView:content];
    TUIView *viewA = [[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    viewA.frame = content.bounds;
    viewA.backgroundColor = [TUIColor blackColor];
    [content setRootView:viewA];
    [viewA setAutoresizingMask:TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize];
    TUIView *viewB = [[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    viewB.backgroundColor = [TUIColor redColor];
    b = viewA.bounds;
    b.origin.y+=30;
    b.size.height-=30;
    viewB.frame = b;
    [viewA addSubview:viewB];
    viewB.autoresizingMask = TUIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize;
    TestVC *testVC = [[TestVC alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    testVC.view.frame = viewB.bounds;
    testVC.view.backgroundColor = [TUIColor yellowColor];
    [viewB addSubview:testVC.view];
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this view in initialized in a `TUIViewController`.  It seems to work fine with a normal `TUIView`, but using a `TUIViewController` messes it up because the view doesn't have its final bounds during `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Can you paste your `-loadView` of your view controller?

Comment: Weird, I can't even get a simple view to show up, let alone a tableView. Here's what my loadView looks like: pastebin.com/ZuC2uFBU

Comment: Thanks for your detailed edit!  I'll look at it and report back later.  I'm not at my machine atm.